# Kerdi shower pan in a shower with 2 drains

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower

Well my simple bathroom refresh has become a full on gut and remodel. I ripped out the tub/shower and plan on turning it into a large walk in shower approx 43" × 72".  Since I already have 2 complete and separate sets of plumbing, and I plan on putting 2 shower heads each with a couple body sprayers. I was thinking it would be wise to use both drains as well, that is easy enough.

My question/problem is, I want to use Schluter Kerdi shower pan system, as this is my first shower. Would it be unwise to take two of 48" × 48" shower pans and cut them down to fit my space, so I can incorporate both drains? I'm afraid cutting them each down so much will reduce the grade of the slope, and be basically counter productive to the purpose of wanting 2 drains. The house was built in the 2000s so it has 2" drain pipes, and to be honest there will probably be very few times all of the shower heads/sprayers will be used at the same time. Am I making this overly complicated? Should I just cut/cap one of the drains, or will my plan provide the benefit I am  hoping for (better drainage)?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely cut off the extra drain.

Even with two shower heads running, you won't exceed the capacity of a properly maintained 2" drain line. In addition to that, it will be more uncomfortable than you think to have a small mountain in the middle of the shower floor.

Good luck. I love the Kerdi shower system.

Comment: Thank you, I think that's what I'll do. Also, since you have used Kerdi before, do you think I'd run into issues if I used a Kerdi shower pan kit w/ durock brand equivalent to kerdi board? I can find Kerdi board in my area, but the local tile show has durock, and it's a bit cheaper.

Comment: Durock isn't waterproofed, and Kerdi board is. You can use Durock, but you will still need a membrane system.